# Cannot Create Tablespace

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle Database 12c.

I am trying to create a tablespace, but whenever I execute the following command, I run into an error:

```
create tablespace ts_something
datafile 'C:\test.dbf'
size 32m autoextend on;
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
ORA-01119: error in creating database file 'C:\test.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.
```

What can I do so that I may successfully create this tablespace?

Comment: Do you have privilege to create files in the root of the C: disk?

Comment: @Littlefoot How may I do this?

Comment: @Littlefoot you're right and he probably does not have the privilege. `O/S-Error: (OS 5) Access is denied.` speaks loud and clear :)

Comment: This is definitely the operating system preventing you from making a mistake, which using your root directory to store application files definitely is. Nature gave us sub-directories for this very reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you (and apparently, you have) already created a database, locate current database files and specify the same directory. Something like this for my XE:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE
```

Comment: You could even `select file_name from dba_data_files where tablespace_name = 'USERS'` in case it's not obvious where the existing data files are.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the CREATE TABLESPACE system privilege.
i.e. to create a tablespace, you must have the SYSDBA system privilege.
Before you can create a tablespace, you must create a database to contain it, and the database must be open.